# How can I extract UI images like icons, windows, buttons from Ubuntu 12?

Tags: icons

I have downloaded the Ubuntu OS for my computer. I needed a few system UI images for my icons and windows, but I am unable to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to http://www.ubuntuthemes.org and download the theme you are interested in. You will find all the icons, wallpapers and images inside the .tar package. If you are on Windows you can uncompress it using 7-Zip for example.

Answer (score 0):

You find the installed icons in

`/usr/share/icons`

and the background images in

`/usr/share/backgrounds`

The icons are separated into subdirectories be theme, kind of icon, and icon size. There are `.png` and `.svg` icons:

```
$ ls /usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/places/48 
distributor-logo.svg  gnome-main-menu.svg  novell-button.svg  start-here.svg
```